# Can I see which gym I put my Pokemon on?

Tags: pokemon-go

I went out last night and places several Pokemon on gyms. Now it is the morning and only one remains where I placed them, but I can't remember which gym I put this Pokemon on. Is there a way to get the game to tell me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's not. To keep track of who went where, screencap your gym defenders when you install them. They should have thought of that though!